# undefined global 3D char array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, global-variables

I want to work with a 3D char array that I would prefer to be global (giving it in argument of every function is too redundant), but the dimensions will be different depending of the arguments of the main function.

So I have something like :

```
char* data[1][1][1];

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]){
    for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i){ /*get dimensions*/ }
    //get somehow char* data[x][y][z] with x,y,z being the dimensions i got in the for
}
```

I tried many things but nothing worked, basically i want kind of an equivalent of the "**new**" keyword in java.

Especially I tried to make data the pointer of a 3D array with the good dimensions I would create after the for loop, but there was an error everytime.

To illustrate a bit the thing :

```
char* data[1][1][1];

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int dim1,dim2,dim3;
    for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i){ 
        /* get dimensions for example : */ 
        dim1 = 2; dim2 = 4; dim3 = 6;
    }
    //get somehow char* data[x][y][z] with x,y,z being the dimensions i got in the for
    char* data2[dim1][dim2][dim3];
    data = data2; //I know it's wrong but that's pretty much where I want to go
}
```

Is there a a way to do it?

Comment: That's not really a "3d" array. It's an array (of unknown size!) of an array of one array of one pointer to `char`. If anything it could be thought of as a "4d" array.

Comment: Is the shown code supposed to demonstrate your problem? Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Yes but in my code I'll use it like data[1][2][6] i need those 3 dimensions, and yes in the first line I put char* data[][1][1] but I could put data[i][j][k] with any values for i,j,k because i want them to be change almost instantly

Comment: ok @Yunnosch ill try to illustrate the problem give me 5 minutes

Comment: You want a VLA (variable length array) at run-time; you can't have a global VLA because global variables must have their size known at link time.  Therefore, you will be obliged to have a VLA argument to the functions, and you'll have to specify the size, too.  AFAIK, you can't even have a pointer to a VLA at global scope -- but if you're going to investigate what's possible, that's where I'd start.

Comment: I see but when I put for exemple  `char* data[1] = "Hello";`  as a global variable and then I change the element data[0], the length is variable too but it works no?

Comment: " i want kind of an equivalent of the "new" keyword in java." I would say that `malloc` is the closest you get

Comment: yes but malloc & calloc cant deal with a multidimensionnal array (or I have to implement the mecanism myself and I'm not good enough yet to not get lost at some point I guess)

Comment: When you use `char *data[1] = "Hello";`, you have a one-element fixed size array that contains a single `char *`.  You may change the string that the pointer points at; do that may change the length of the string that is pointed at.  But the array itself is still the same size -- the size of one `char *`.  Strings in C are different from strings in other languages, in case you hadn't gathered.

Comment: God yes I had, well I understand why it's impossible I'll stick with the solution where I put my data array as argument in each function, thanks for the explanation guys